# Create a group model for users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I built a web app in Rails where i have articles about different subjects like a blog basically. Now I want to add a group model on my users so that I can show some articles for only those that belong to a certain group. I use devise to handle my users today. They have email and a password as login.

I've been looking everywhere for a gem that i could use and i have searched google and stackoverflow but i haven't found anything except Groupify that resemble what I'm looking for and that is poorly documented :(

So first of all.. are there any gems out there that could help me with this? If not, does anyone has a good way to sort this?

I'm using Rails 4 for my app and Postgres as my database. I use the latest Devise.

I want to point out that I'm pretty new at Rails.

Comment: We would need more insight about the expected behaviour.. how do you plan to add your users to groups? Can they subscribe to a group? Are you adding them "by hand"? How are articles linked to groups? Have you thought about implementing some sort of tagging capabilities? etc..

Comment: The idea is that i want to add premium content to the site. So they subscribe for content and they will now be able to read articles that isn't available for everyone. So they idea is that ones they have paid they will be automatically added a a "premium" group and can now see the premium content. Does this give you more of an idea of what i'm looking for?

Comment: Well I suppose you could go with CanCan as stated by someone below, although this could be implemented with a more general approach.. say it's a blog so at some point you could want to be able to tag your articles so that you can separate your content and group by themes, maybe you could use this to tag your articles as "premium" for instance.

Comment: I just checked out Groupify, for which the github page gives a good intro. It's been a few months since you asked the question, maybe you should check it out again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the cancan gem can help you:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=cancan

Comment: For authorization gems, Authority is a better choice these days. https://github.com/nathanl/authority The CanCan gem has 250+ issues and 60+ pull requests and hasn't been "touched" in almost a year. Authority on the other hand is actively maintained.

Comment: Cancan was taken over by the community and is now called "Cancancan". You can find it at https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "groups" you are describing could be thought of as roles the users can have and you'd like to restrict authorization based on which roles they have.

If that's the case, you can take a look at the rolify gem: https://github.com/EppO/rolify

If that's not the case or that's overkill for what you are doing, I would probably not worry too much about finding a gem and instead just make a Group model that does what you want.

Comment: To Bruno's point, Rolify by itself might not be everything you are desiring and if you'd like something to handle the authorization rules, then try also adding Authority: https://github.com/nathanl/authority

Comment: Well i've been looking at rolify and i'm not sure that roles are what i'm looking for. However i got a tip about looking at pundit last night, i was at a rails meetup and they suggested that maybe pundit could solve my problems using an approach with policies instead. I guess roles/policies and groups could perform similar functionality.